# SQL Server plan caching on very similar but different queries

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, query-cache

Say I have a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Investors
WHERE 1=1  
AND 
(
    investerName IN (SELECT investerName FROM Assets WHERE Assets.CompanyID=Investors.CompanyID AND Assets.CompanyID = @companyID )
    OR investerName IN 
        (
            SELECT investerName FROM InvestmentEnrollments WHERE InvestmentEnrollments .CompanyID=Investors.CompanyIDAND InvestmentEnrollments .state IN (3,4) AND InvestmentEnrollments.CompanyID = @companyID         
        )
) 
AND Investors.CompanyID=@companyID
```

and another similar query like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Investors
WHERE 1=1  
AND 
(
    investerName IN (SELECT investerName FROM Assets WHERE Assets.CompanyID=Investors.companyID AND Assets.companyID = @companyID )
    OR investerName IN 
        (
            SELECT investerName FROM InvestmentEnrollments WHERE InvestmentEnrollments .companyID=Investors.companyID AND InvestmentEnrollments.state IN (3,4) AND InvestmentEnrollments.companyID = @companyID         
        )
) 
AND Investors.companyID=@companyID
AND Investors.userName = @someInvestorUserName
```

Both queries are similar enough but the second one has he additional where predicate.  So what does SQL Server do in this case?  Does it try to fit both into the same query plan?  Or are these considered two distinct queries requiring different query plans?

Comment: Why not just to test it by yourself? Turn "Include Actual Execution plan" and compare it.

Comment: @TimofeyGMorozov Comparing two execution plans tells nothing about whether is the same execution plan, executed twice, or two different execution plans that happen to contain exactly the same operators and the same parameters. You would need to look at [`sys.dm_exec_requests.sql_plan_handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) being executed.

Comment: In defense of @TimofeyGMorozov answer, the plans look a little different so one could guess that these are different plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The queries are not only different text, they are semantically different. These are distinct queries, requirying distinct execution plans. Nothing in common.